# elelctric potential from a laser

Tags: atomic-physics, schroedinger-equation

The average intensity from elecreomagnetic waves are given by:

$$I=c \frac{E_{av}^2 \epsilon_0}{2}$$

I want to find what strength of a laser one needs to apply to get below the binding energy of a 1s e for hydrogen. My attempt

effective potential:

$$V_e=-k\frac{e^2}{r}+\frac{l(l+1)\hbar}{2m r^2}   [J]$$

U=potential

$$E=-\frac{dU}{dr}$$

From the units of the effective potential we see that the E field is:

$$E=-\frac{d V_e}{dr}\frac{1}{e}=k er^{-2}-2\frac{l(l+1)\hbar}{2me} r^{-3}$$

We want to push the electron below the 1s radius so we apply a laser with intensity  $$I=c\frac{E_{max}^2\epsilon}{2}=1000   [W/m^2]$$

solving for $$E_{max}=867.7$$

adding a new equation for the electric field (which is the accelration) and setting it equal to 0 to see where the force balance is 0:

$$-\frac{d V_e}{dr}\frac{1}{e}=k er^{-2}-2\frac{l(l+1)\hbar}{2me} r^{-3}=-867.7$$

and solving for r we obtain:  $$r=1.06*10^{-10}$$

but then r>bohr radius and I wanted to push it below bohr radius with a laser?

Comment: The question is not particularly clear. Why set I=1000 W/m^2? (By the way, the standard unit in strong-field communities is actually W/cm^2, for whatever reason, so you might as well start using it.) What units is 867.7 in? What is it, *exactly*, that you want to do, and how does it relate to the calculations you display?

Answer (score 0):

In general you obtain high electric field intensities by using ultrafast laser pulses, and focus the pulse to the optical limit.  For example, the ["Lambda Cubed"](http://cuos.engin.umich.edu/researchgroups/hfs/facilities/lambdacubed/)  laser at the University of Michigan is capable of producing intensities on the order of $5 \times 10^{18} W/cm^2$.  And this is with an average power of less than a watt, divided into a thousand pulses per second, each of less than 20 femtoseconds.

It's easy enough to generate lower intensities; you can start with the focal spot size and then determine the intensity required.  Note that the "tip" of a Gaussian beam has a higher intensity than the edges, so you can just work with the tip if you have good optics. I've accidentally generated plasma on the inside of a vacuum chamber at $10^{14} W/cm^2}. Oops.

To target individual atoms with a very small radius would require a corresponding wavelength, which is easy to compute but not possible to generate with a laser.

Comment: There are no strong-field experiments on single atoms to my knowledge - you either focus into a diffuse gas cell or into a gas jet, depending on what you want to do. The intensity you quote is much higher than the regime the OP is looking for, which corresponds to the barrier suppression threshold. At 5E18 you will ionize above-the-barrier, and then re-ionize again and again and again; to my knowledge the highest charged species yet is Xe$^{26+}$ but that's likely outdated. But otherwise, yeah, that.

Comment: I found a solution but I am not sure about it:  $$V_c=-ke^2/z$$ pot of the external field:  $$V_e=-ez E_0$$  $$V_{net}=V_c+V_E$$ differentiate: $$\frac{dV_{net}}{dz}=k\frac{e^2}{z^2}-eE_0$$ solving for 0 with bohr radius  $$E_0=9*10^9*1.6*10^{-19}/(0.529*10^{-10})^2=5.14*10^{11}$$ solving for intensity:  $$I=c \frac{(E_0)^2\epsilon}{2}=3.51*10^{22}$$ Is this a correct theoretical approach? And why do they define the pot of the external field this way?

Comment: @fisher Without units that calculation is particularly hard to follow. But if you got $I=3.5\times 10^{22}\:\mathrm{W/m^2}$ for the barrier suppression in hydrogen, that is probably too high by about two orders of magnitude. There is no requirement that the barrier suppression will have a barrier top at $z=a_0$; instead, you need to solve for $z$ as a function of $E_0$ and then find the potential energy at the top of the barrier. When $E_0$ is high enough that the top of the hill is below the ground state energy $E_g=-I_p$, we say the barrier has been suppressed.

Comment: (And, again, putting your results in W/cm^2 will make it much easier to compare with published figures as well as for strong-fielders to evaluate intuitively. Weird as a newcomer but that's what it is.) Finally, all of this should be in the question itself!